# Write multiple log4j files with different info

Tags: java, log4j

The API I am working on cannot be connected to a database, but need to log events that are happening in the API. To do this I was thinking on using log4j to create log file with API event information.

The problem is that all log entries end up in both logs, and not separated.

**Requirements I am need to fulfill**

- Multiple log files with certain information inside
- Backup log files live indefinitely

**Log4j properties file**

```
log4j.rootLogger=QuietAppender, LoudAppender, FirstLog, SecondLog, TRACE

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n

# setup A1
log4j.appender.QuietAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.QuietAppender.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.QuietAppender.File=${wls.logs-path}/test-api/test-api-info.log
log4j.appender.QuietAppender.MaxFileSize=512KB
log4j.appender.QuietAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.QuietAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n
# Keep three backup files.
log4j.appender.QuietAppender.MaxBackupIndex=100
# Pattern to output: date priority [category] - message
log4j.appender.QuietAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.QuietAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n

# setup A2
log4j.appender.LoudAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LoudAppender.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.LoudAppender.File=${wls.logs-path}/test-api/test-api-debug.log
log4j.appender.LoudAppender.MaxFileSize=512KB
# Keep three backup files.
log4j.appender.LoudAppender.MaxBackupIndex=3
# Pattern to output: date priority [category] - message
log4j.appender.LoudAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LoudAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n

# setup FirstLog
log4j.appender.FirstLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FirstLog.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.FirstLog.File=${wls.logs-path}/test-api/first-info.log
log4j.appender.FirstLog.MaxFileSize=10240kB
log4j.appender.FirstLog.MaxBackupIndex=99999
log4j.appender.FirstLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FirstLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n

# setup SecondLog
log4j.appender.SecondLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.SecondLog.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.SecondLog.File=${wls.logs-path}/test-api/second-info.log
log4j.appender.SecondLog.MaxFileSize=10240kB
log4j.appender.SecondLog.MaxBackupIndex=99999
log4j.appender.SecondLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SecondLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - %m%n
```

**Java Class**

```
private static final Logger logkp = Logger.getLogger("FirstLog");
private static final Logger logda = Logger.getLogger("SecondLog");

logkp.info(sb.toString());
logda.info(sb.toString());
```

**Current Results**

```
2015-05-27 10:27:46,175 INFO [SecondLog] - 12645,APIServer1,0,000bdc5000000100011055042d0114a6

2015-05-27 10:27:46,583 INFO [FirstLog] - APIServer1,Caller,test-Version-1.0,certValue,1
2015-05-27 10:28:22,458 INFO [SecondLog] - 12645,APIServer1,0,000bdc5000000100011055042d0114a6

2015-05-27 10:28:22,793 INFO [FirstLog] - APIServer1,Caller,test-Version-1.0,certValue,1

2015-05-27 10:28:25,203 INFO [SecondLog] - 12645,APIServer1,0,000bdc5000000100011055042d0114a6

2015-05-27 10:28:25,528 INFO [FirstLog] - APIServer1,Caller,test-Version-1.0,certValue,1

2015-05-27 10:28:26,686 INFO [SecondLog] - 12645,APIServer1,0,000bdc5000000100011055042d0114a6
```

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. Are you running into a problem?

Comment: Yes, it is posting all of the things for First log and Second log in both the files and not each respectively.

Comment: Have you tried setting the additivity to false? As is, all logging is going to the root logger and thus to all appenders.

Comment: And  I guess, you'll have to define loggers and add the appenders respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm not 100% sure about this**, because it's been a while that I was using log4j and we used to write the configuration in xml, but I think you have to create loggers like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=QuietAppender, LoudAppender, TRACE
log4j.logger.FirstLogger = FirstLog, INFO
log4j.additivity.FirstLogger = false
log4j.logger.SecondLogger = SecondLog, INFO
log4j.additivity.SecondLogger = false

... // then configure appenders as you did
```

To get the outputs you want. Setting the additivity to false "cuts" the connection to the rootLogger. It is set to true by default and will cause all logmessages to be appended to the logger and to all ancestors of the logger. Setting it to false will change that.

If your API has its own namespace - let's say "my.own.API" then you could also create an API-Logger like this:

```
log4j.logger.my.own.API = MyAPIAppender, INFO
log4j.additivity.my.own.API = false
```

And create loggers like this:

```
package my.own.API

public class MyAPIClass{
    private static Logger apiLog = Logger.getLogger(MyAPIClass.class);
    // ...
}
```